# What is the correct way of retrieving a given business object from a list of business objects using LINQ Where vs. Find?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following list of items:

```
List<Item> items = Item.GetSomeItems();
```

And I wanted to retrieve a particular item with an id from the list of items:

```
int itemID = 2;
```

Which of the following ways would be the correct and proper ways of retrieving the item?

```
Item item = items.Find(x => x.ItemID == itemID);
```

or

```
Item item items.Where(x => x.ItemID == itemID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Maybe neither of these are the best solution out there using LINQ.  Either way, an explanation for the best approach would be helpful since I retrieve individual business object items often. When to use which function would be great too. Thank you.

Comment: You do realize that both solutions do a linear search of the `List`, yes?  If you do this a lot, consider another data structure, i.e. `Dictionary` (or only fetching the Item you want from the database).

Comment: In context, this is a filtered list for the user by date. (for a report) The user selects criteria/options within this filtered list. (That has already been shown to the user) I don't see how a dictionary would help. I didn't give the context because I wasn't asking about design practices, but rather the best way to fetch an item from a list.

Comment: If you aren't doing it a lot, or the list is small, then it's not a big deal, but it's inheriently inefficient to search an unsorted List for a single item.  You have no choice but to just check every single one.  If you use a dictionary, for example, it is specifically designed for fetching objects based on a key that's an object, rather than based on it's position.  It will be far more efficient if you are doing a lot of searching over a large set of data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The list is not big, but I will keep this in mind when working with large data sets. From my understanding, a list lookup is faster if it is a small list due to the slight overhead of a dictionary.

Comment: The overhead for a Dictionary is in creating it, not searching it.  If you have more than 2 or 3 items searching a Dictionary will probably be quicker.  The main drawbacks are that it consumes a fair bit more memory than a List, and doesn't maintain ordering (in the event that you need ordering).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the implementation differences are between `Find()` and `Where()`. Although I suspect by coincidence they're the same, I'd recommend sticking with the LINQ extension methods (`Where()`, `Single[OrDefault]()` etc) rather than methods specific to the collection implementation you've chosen. Because they're extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` you have more flexibility to choose a different collection implementation if you want to.

**For bonus points:**

A couple of things worry me here though - you're loading things from somewhere, then filtering them in memory after that. I'd prefer to see something more akin to:

```
Item item = Item.GetItemForId(2);
```

Which leaves the filtering to the (presumably) database. Although that probably violates SRP, so in fact you're heading for:

```
IRepository<Item> repository = this.itemRepository;
Item item = repository.Get(2);
```

If you were using full Linq to SQL/Entities you'd be able to make use of deffered execution and do something like:

```
Item item = context.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == 2);
```

This will not load all the items before calling `SingleOrDefault()`, instead it will look at the who expression and generate the appropriate SQL for it, something like:

```
SELECT [fields] FROM Item WHERE Id = @id
```

This is all an assumption on my part, but I did want to make it clear that there's a big difference between *Linq to Entities (Entity Framework)* and *Linq to SQL*, which build SQL statements to send to a database, versus *Linq to Objects* which is the same method calls, but working on in-memory collection objects.

Comment: Thanks Neil. The above code was just an example, but you do bring up some important points. I use entity framework 4.1, so I don't use a repository. I do have a few Lists in memory, but it is common to make multiple iterations through them and I keep them in memory so I can minimize trips to the database.

Comment: If you're using EF (with a DbContext) then rather than `context.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == 2)` I would suggest using the DbSet.Find method because it will search in memory before hitting the database. e.g: `context.Items.Find(2)`. The parameters are variable and should be supplied in the same order as the properties in the PrimaryKey specification for the entity - this usually is just a single `int` or `Guid` though.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitrely better use a second case `.FirstOrDefault()` if you *expect* that specified value can be **not** present in collection and that is a **not** an exceptional case.

Also note that `Find()` is a method of `List<T>`, instead `Where()` is an *extension* method, that *can* be applied to *any* type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so by using in your code `Where()` you gain more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like the following:

```
Item item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == itemID);
```

Depending on how you want it to work, choose between Single, SingleOrDefault, First, and FirstOrDefault as the LINQ method to use.  Single will throw an error if more than one item in the list matches the query, First will simply return the first one it encounters that matches the query.  Without the OrDefault, they will throw an error if no matches are found, with it it will return null in that case.  This is nicer than trying to use a null and getting a null reference exception.

So e.g. if you only want to handle the case where there is exactly one item that matches the ItemID, use Single.  If it's not invalid to have more than one, and you want to gracefully handle having none match, use FirstOrDefault and check if the resulting item is null before using it.

Comment: +1 for explaining `Single/First/OrDefault` and dropping the `Where`.